# Exit code non-zero and unable to see output logs

Tags: google-cloud-ml

How do I view stdout/stderr output logs for cloud ML? I've tried using gcloud beta logging read and also gcloud beta ml jobs stream-logs and nothing... all I see are the INFO level logs generated by the system i.e. "Tearing down TensorFlow".

Also in the case where I have an error that shows the docker container exited with non zero code.  It links me to a GUI page that shows the same stuff as gcloud beta ml jobs stream-logs.  Nothing that shows me the actual output from the console of what my job produced...

Help please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the case that the Cloud ML service account does not have permissions to write to your project's StackDriver Logs, or the Logging API is not enabled on your project.

First check whether the Stackdriver Logging API is enabled for the project by going to the API manager: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/logging.googleapis.com/overview?project=[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]

Then Cloud ML service account should be automatically added as an Editor to the project, and therefore allows it to write to the project logs, but if you have changed your project permissions it may have lost it. If so, check that you've manually given the Cloud ML service account LogWriter permissions.

If you are unsure of the service account used by Cloud ML, this page has instructions on how to find it: https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/using-external-buckets