# Cloud ML Training job has stalled while 'Waiting for TensorFlow to start up.'

Tags: google-cloud-ml

My training job has stalled and the cloud ml logs just say 'Waiting for TensorFlow to start up.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exit code non-zero and unable to see output logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982520/exit-code-non-zero-and-unable-to-see-output-logs)

Answer (score 1):

Your job might be running but not have permission to write to your logs.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39983269/5441818