# ML Engine: Access Prediction Logs

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'd like to access prediction logs for my model hosted on ML Engine.  I've looked at this answer:

[Exit code non-zero and unable to see output logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982520/exit-code-non-zero-and-unable-to-see-output-logs)

and I have the StackDriver logging API enabled.  How would I access the logs generated for each model prediction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the logs that are produced contain metadata, Apache-log style (e.g. timestamp, some latency information, etc.). They do *not* contain the requests (inputs) or responses (predictions). To enable these logs, see the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/prediction-overview#prediction_logging

If you're interested in logging the request and responses, we're currently gathering information and would love to hear about your requirements. Please reach out to cloudml-feedback@google.com and we'll ask you a few questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  In the docs, I see `You can set online prediction logging for a model by setting onlinePredictionLogging to true (True in Python) in the Model resource you use when creating your model with projects.models.create. If you use the gcloud command-line tool to create your model, include the --enable-logging flag when you run gcloud ml-engine models create.` Is there a way to check that I have this enabled?  I'm using a model that's already on ML Engine.  For what it's worth, it looks like I do have the StackDriver logging API enabled

Comment: `gcloud ml-engine models describe` should tell you info about your model. If you do *not* see anything, it is not enabled (which, by the way, is the default behavior since logs cost you additional money, we don't enable them by default). It may be possible to update an existing model with this setting using `gcloud ml-engine models update`, but I cannot recall for certain.